# Xcode build post script for build failed

Tags: xcode6, continuous-integration, teamcity

How can I detect build failed status in post action script from Xcode edit scheme section for different targets?

I am planning to send sms to me if build is failed in CI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Post build scripts (specified in the Xcode project file) are only executed if the build passes, but not when it fails.

If you want to handle this case you should use a Continuous Integration solution (ex: https://fastlane.tools/) or service (https://bitrise.io/ - CTO here), or simply write a script which calls Xcode's Command Line Tool `xcodebuild` which returns an error code if it can't perform the given action (build, archive, test, ...), so you can handle this case the way you want to in the script.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am using teamcity where xcodebuild is command for build, but how do I got the build status?

Comment: I don't know how TeamCity handles the exit codes but in a simple bash script you can get the last command's exit code with `$?` - but this depends on the script/tool.